# twilio-python 6.5.0: Instance of 'Client' has no 'studio' member

Tags: twilio

I'm running Python 3.7.2 and using twilio version 6.5.0.

I'm trying to execute a Twilio Flow using Python. I'm using the following sample code, copied directly from [Twilio's docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/execution?code-sample=code-create-an-execution-with-custom-parameters&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x):

```
# Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest import Client


# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
# DANGER! This is insecure. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth_token = 'your_auth_token'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

execution = client.studio \
                  .flows('FWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') \
                  .executions \
                  .create(parameters={
                       'foo': 'bar'
                   }, to='+15558675310', from_='+15017122661')

print(execution.sid)
```

I get the following error:
`Instance of 'Client' has no 'studio' member`

Obviously I've changed the Flow ID, the `to` and the `from_` values accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

So I found my solution.

I initially installed the python-twilio client last night and during that time `pip install twilio` pulled down package version `6.5.0`. A coworker suggested Twilio may have accidentally pushed that release early and unfinished and suggested that I uninstall the package and reinstall and sure enough, pip now pulled down twilio version `6.29.0` which then worked.

So if anyone else comes across this, there's your answer.

Comment: Glad you got this sorted. Version 6.5.0 was likely not unfinished, but released before the Studio API was available. We do recommend using the latest version of the library to ensure you have the most up to date features.

Comment: 6.5.0 comes after 6.29.0.

6.29.0 has studio, and 6.5.0 seems to be the latest version.

Comment: 29 is definitely bigger than 5, so is a later version 

Comment: touche! I was reading it as 2.9! Thanks for the help, @philnash! Do you know why `pip install` would have pulled down 2.5 instead of anything later?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with how pip works, so I don't know why it would have got the older version, sorry.